# jquery Ajax URl issue

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have looked around quite a bit and it seems absolute urls is the way to go here. I have no problem in chrome but firefox and IE IE still wants to redirect fully to the wrong page.

my states:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        $('#page_submit').click(function () {

            event.preventDefault();

            $('.standard span').hide();

            var pw = $("input#pw").val();  
            if (pw == "") {
                $("span#pw_err").show();
                $("input#pw").focus();  
                return false;  
            }

            var pw2 = $("input#pw2").val();  
            if (pw2 == "") {
                $("span#pw2_err").show();
                $("input#pw2").focus();  
                return false;  
            }

            if (pw != pw2) {
                $("span#match_err").show();
                $("input#pw2").focus();  
                return false;  
            }           

            var data = 'pw=' + pw + '&pw2=' + pw2;

            $('.standard input').attr('disabled','true');
            $('.loading').show();

            $.ajax({
                url: "/members/includes/change.php",
                type: "GET",
                data: data,
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) {
                    //hide the form
                    $('#pw_form').fadeOut('slow');

                    //display results
                    $('#pw_form_result').fadeIn('slow');
                    $("#pw_form_result").html(html);
                }       
            });

            return false;
        });     
    });
</script>
```

the structure of the file I am trying to access is:

> www.site.com/members/includes/change.php

Not sure what the cause is really. I know the jquery initiator is working because i can summon alert calls to and from the function itself.

### edit

after commenting out

> event.preventDefault();

it seems to function right? everything I had read before said this was a necessary piece however.

Comment: you don't have event variable and you already have return false so event.preventDefault() was unneccesarry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
$('#page_submit').click(function () {
```

should be

```
$('#page_submit').click(function (event) {
```

so this code

```
event.preventDefault();
```

can take effect.

And the 'return false;' is unneccesarry.